# Why do myelinated axons conduct impulses faster?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurology

How does the myelination help in better conduction? I would prefer answers that are not too technical please.

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: @Imi, be sure to check out my newly added [answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57622/16866) to the linked question. I added it here first, but moved it after this question got close votes as a duplicate.

Comment: And where did this comment go 0.o?

Comment: [Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/why-is-saltatory-conduction-in-myelinated-axons-faster-than-continuous-conductio/57622#57622)